# AWS XRay wrong service map when using OpenFeign with AppMesh and AWS Service Discovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, microservices, openfeign, aws-app-mesh

I'm testing interservice communication with Spring Boot Rest services deployed on AWS with AppMesh and Service Discovery enabled. To be able to send messages from service a to service b I've to use the OpenFeign client to generate a proxy class.

**Tech Stack**

- Spring Boot OpenFeign
- AWS XRay
- ECS
- ECR
- Sleuth
- AppMesh (Virtual Node, Virtual Service)
- AWS Service Discovery (instead of Eureka)

**Expected Behavior**

In AWS XRay, it should show a call trace:

Client -> ServiceA -> ServiceB

**Actual Behavior**

In AWS XRay, I can see the call traces:

Client -> ServiceA
Client -> ServiceB

[image: xray trace]

Another question would be how to tell OpenFeign to use the HttpClient from AWS SDK?

**Other Information**

Repository available at: https://github.com/czetsuya/lab-microservice-spring-aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by using a dynamicNamingStrategy in tracingFilter

```
@Bean
  public Filter tracingFilter(final AWSXRayRecorder awsxRayRecorder) {

    log.info("Setting up AWS Xray tracing filter");
    return new AWSXRayServletFilter(SegmentNamingStrategy.dynamic(Optional.ofNullable(AWS_XRAY_SEGMENT_NAME).orElse(
        "xray-filter")));
  }
```

And create an HttpClientBuilder bean.

```
@Bean
  public HttpClientBuilder xrayHttpClientBuilder() {

    log.info("Setting up AWS xray http client configuration");
    return HttpClientBuilder.create();
  }
```

AWS XRay should now show the HTTP requests in the trace:
[image: AWS XRay Trace]

The project code is available at https://github.com/czetsuya/lab-microservice-spring-aws.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have found solution yet, the snippet code below could help you:

Firstly you need to use Feign Http Client:

```
implementation 'io.github.openfeign:feign-httpclient:9.5.0'
```

Create Feign Builder which use apache http client from aws xray

```
    @Bean
    public Feign.Builder feignBuilder() {
        //aws xray http client
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        return Feign.builder()
                .retryer(Retryer.NEVER_RETRY)
                .client(new ApacheHttpClient(client));
    }
```

Initialize your client:

```
@Bean
    CallingService TestSnsPushNotificationApis(@Autowired Feign.Builder builder) {
        return builder.target(CallingService.class, "http://localhost:8081");
    }
```

Comment: Hi. I'm using the FeignClient annotation on a proxy class https://github.com/czetsuya/lab-microservice-spring-aws/blob/main/job-services/src/main/java/com/czetsuyatech/jobs/web/controllers/ApplicantProxy.java. It should automatically use the FeignBuilder, unless there's an additional configuration that needs to be done?